# append() function is not working in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to `append` a form but its not responding. Is there any solution for this?

when i click below button

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">Assign Task</span>
</div>
```

then it opens

> paste.ofcode.org/U5pWqiQmsM8BAaUS3dA2X6

by using this:

```
  $('.create-task-btn1').click(function(){
     $('.create-task-form1').stop().slideToggle();
  });
```

then i add "append" class in button and add this code which is below ,,, and after it it stoped working, "its class not id"

```js
$('.append').click(function() {
  $('table-bordered').append('
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">
                            <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" 
                                style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>');
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">Assign Task</span>
</div>
```

simply i wants that when i click on assign btn then below form comes once with finish btn and when i click again and again then it comes without finish button like https://ibb.co/QYCR45P

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I suspect because otherwise there is an error for "not enough text" or something. The intention behind the error message is to get people to describe their problem. And this is a perfect example *why* - what is the problem here? What's happening? What's supposed to be happening? Any errors?

Comment: JS does not support multi line strings. You must either each line add to concatenation or add `\` and the end of each line. Your console had to throw errors. Have you checked it?

Comment: It's because you cannot include line breaks in a string literal. Use a template literal, or concatenate each line together. Better still, move all of that HTML out of your JS entirely, they shouldn't be that tightly related. Instead put the HTML in to to the DOM when the page loads, hide it if necessary, then `clone()` and display it when needed.

Comment: Always check the error console!

Comment: Is table-bordered a tag or a class?

Comment: $('table-bordered')-->tag or class/id and please add in your html this tag or class/id

Comment: Where you want to `append` so where is appending target `class` or `id`?

Comment: plz check the updated question

Comment: @ParasRaiyani its class now i added the dot plz check the updated question

Comment: @GauravPunjabi its class now i added the dot plz check the updated question

Comment: @RaeeshAlam its class now i added the dot plz check the updated question

Comment: @Justinas plz check the updated question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan plz check the updated question

Comment: @alphadev Check my snippet below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.append').click(function() {
$('#table-bordered').append(`<div class="container"><div class="row"><form action="#" 
id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate"><table 
class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><th scope="row" style="font-size: 
14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td colspan="3"><input type="text" 
class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><td rowspan="3"><a data-id="" data- 
toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; 
font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" 
style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input 
type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><th style="font-size: 
14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input type="text" 
class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div> 
</div>`);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="col-md-4">
  <span class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">Assign Task</span>
</div>

<div id="table-bordered">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try using this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">Assign Task</span>
</div>
 <form class="table-bordered">

 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.append').click(function() {
  $('.table-bordered').append('<div class="container"><div class="row"><form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate"><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><td rowspan="3"><a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div></div>');
});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the template as a single string, ie without line breaks and use `tilde operator` (`) to specify the start and end of template string.

I believe you are appending this table to a DOM element (div or form) whose class name is `table-bordered` :)

```
$('.append').click(function() {
$('.table-bordered').append(`<div class="container"><div class="row"><form action="#" 
id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate"><table 
class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><th scope="row" style="font-size: 
14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td colspan="3"><input type="text" 
class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><td rowspan="3"><a data-id="" data- 
toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; 
font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" 
style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input 
type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td><th style="font-size: 
14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><td><input type="text" 
class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div> 
</div>`);
});
```

Comment: Dont forget to add dot `$(.table-bordered)` for selecting by class name.

Comment: it opens makes a new one and at again click it closes

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will solve your problem

```js
$('.append').click(function() {
      $('.table-bordered').append(`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">
                            <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn"
                                style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                        <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>`);
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span class="btn btn-info append">Assign Task</span>
 
</div>
 <div class="table-bordered"></div>
```

Comment: i just click on it once but it opens a lot of times

Comment: no, it's open within few seconds, the time required because of I added bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple line of html element so there is need to add this **`** operator.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$('.append').click(function() {  
  $('.append-target').append(`<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
        <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                  <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">Assign Task</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="append-target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd put your code in a empty tag. Your code is not clear but I can help you.
Take a look of this piece of code, maybe is useful:

--- Before at all you need a span to append your form:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="table-append"></span>
</div>
```

--- In your script tag (put in at the end before the ):

```
<script>
        $('.append').click(function() {
            $(".table-append").append(`<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                    <td rowspan="3">
                                        <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" 
                                            style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                    <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>`);
        });
    </script>
```

Your table code is put between ´´ to avoid concatenated strings.

Hope this answer can help you!